# Why some attribute names start with double underscore in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, double-underscore

I see some attributes of some objects in JavaScript start with double underscore. For example, something like `__defineGetter__` or `__defineSetter__` or `__proto__`.
Is it a convention defined ECMAScript specification? Or maybe it's just a convention in the developer community?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

These are properties **defined by the specific browser** and *are not defined by ECMAScript*.

Therefore, [name collision](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_collision) needs to be avoided. If they called the property `defineGetter`, then there would be no guarantee that the website's code didn't already define a property by that same name -- and that would cause many problems. However, appending two underscores has become the defacto way to define browser specific properties (since it's much less likely some website will use that convention).

You may notice that other browsers start using the same naming convention as others (like using `__proto__`), but that's still not universally guaranteed between all browsers (eg, IE does not define the `__proto__ property`).

Also: the convention of using two underscores for "system-defined" identifiers (as opposed to programmer-defined identifiers) harkens back a long time, so I don't know when that convention "started" -- At least as long as C++ (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling#Simple_example )

Comment: So, up to here, double underscores is a _defacto_ standard of browsers, one underscore is that _defacto_ standard of libraries (like Microsoft.Ajax or jQuery). Am I right?

Comment: I do not think that there is an overarching convention for how frameworks define their variables. Yet, the "best practice" is to define only 1 global object (like `google` object or `jQuery` object) and then define all of your methods/variables within the scope of that object. And that's to avoid exactly the problem of name collision. However, by no means does that mean that every framework does it that way.

Comment: Furthermore, browser variables are often not global variables at all like framework variables sometimes are. They are normally properties added to every object. Maybe via `Object.prototype` or some other way.

Comment: ECMAScript specs have changed, now __proto__ is included in the specification. See the bottom answer

Answer (score 7):

This is so that **name collision** would be very unlikely.

JavaScript has this problem with global namespace which everyone can change or access anything. There are some data hiding techniques but sometimes will not work.

For example if you do this, your jquery will stop working:

```
$ = "somethingElse";
```

Comment: But is it a recommended practice, or is it just a kind of innovation, decided by some guru guys? I mean why start it with underscore and nothing else, and why double underscores, not one?

Comment: Using two underscores for "system-defined" variables and not User-defined variables harkens back a long time, so I don't know when that convention "started" -- At least as long as C++ (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling#Simple_example)

Answer (score 5):

I believe the answer needs an update. These names are now part of ECMA-262, so yes, the naming convention is now *defined in ECMAScript specification*.

Starting from ECMAScript 2015 (ES6), the following has been standardized*:

- [B.2.2.1 Object.prototype.`__proto__`](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-object.prototype.__proto__)

Starting from ECMAScript 2017 (ES8), the following has been standardized*:

- [B.2.2.2 Object.prototype.`__defineGetter__`( *P*, *getter* )](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/index.html#sec-object.prototype.__defineGetter__)
- [B.2.2.3 Object.prototype.`__defineSetter__`( *P*, *setter* )](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/index.html#sec-object.prototype.__defineSetter__)
- B.2.2.4 Object.prototype.`__lookupGetter__` ( *P* )
- B.2.2.5 Object.prototype.`__lookupSetter__` ( *P* )

*: It should be noted however, the sections listed above are all defined in Annex B "Additional ECMAScript Features for Web Browsers", and a note accompanying Annex B reads (emphasis mine)

> This annex describes various legacy features and other characteristics of web browser based ECMAScript implementations. All of the language features and behaviours specified in this annex have one or more undesirable characteristics and **in the absence of legacy usage would be removed from this specification.** However, the usage of these features by large numbers of existing web pages means that web browsers must continue to support them. The specifications in this annex define the requirements for interoperable implementations of these legacy features.
>
> These features are not considered part of the core ECMAScript language. **Programmers should not use or assume the existence of these features and behaviours** when writing new ECMAScript code. ECMAScript **implementations are discouraged from implementing these features** unless the implementation is part of a web browser or is required to run the same legacy ECMAScript code that web browsers encounter.

effectively deprecating their usage.